# When I start my Dell Latitude E4300, I get an "Intel® Matrix Storage Manager option ROM" message after the Dell logo, then a BSOD as Windows XP starts

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, bsod, dell-latitude

The computer is a Dell Latitude E4300 with a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 500 GB hard drive.

I used an automatic driver installer CD to install any drivers not installed on the system.  When I rebooted my computer, I got the following text after the Dell logo, which I've never seen:

```
Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager option ROM ... (C) 2003 ...
```

Afterwards, I got a blue screen when trying to boot Windows XP (my system had both Windows XP and Windows 7) with white text for about one second before the system reboots.  I tried reformatting the hard drive as well as deleting and recreating the partitions, but I still get the blue screen.  What should I do?

Comment: You might want to register an account here. Once you have done so, submit an edit to the question containing the text of the blue screen, and I'll approve it and flag your question for a moderator so that your unregistered account is merged with the account you just registered.  This will ensure that you retain ownership of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be caused by the version of the `iastor.sys` driver (used for Intel storage controllers) that is supplied with Windows XP.  Download the latest version of the drivers from the Intel Download Center [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology%20%28Intel%C2%AE%20RST%29).  You may need to download the driver diskette files and create a 3.5" floppy disk containing drivers to use during installation of Windows XP, a process which requires a USB floppy disk drive and blank floppy disks.

I know that this isn't your computer, but [some Lenovo systems had this problem as well](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT003602), and it appears that you are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Hi , First ? I Wanna Say , thank You so much

Comment: @WalidFromAlgeria: Just rewrote the answer.  If this works for you, click on the check below the up/down voting controls to accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks DragonLord , Look : I purchased it but not from the Dell company , Ok ? I'm The Second buyer . I'm From Algeria ... Thank you So Much

Comment: Al-Salam Alikom (Islamic greeting..Huhh) Ladies-Gentlemen :

Comment: Al-Salam Alikom (Islamic greeting..Huhh) Ladies-Gentlemen : i wanted to say that the problem is fixed , Thanks to God and thanks to your efforts . I hope all of you THE BEST (IN CHA ALLAH) And I Hope that God gives you what it's The Most Good In The Word (PARADIS), And What You Dream For . Sorry For The ... You Know . Bye.

Comment: @WalidFromAlgeria You're welcome. :)